# Comment traduire l'adjectif « hungry » (au figuré ; [adjectif] et « hungry », ...to learn, to stay...) ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

En anglais on a le sens figuré de l'adjectif [*hungry*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hungry#Adjective) pour « eager, having an avid desire (‘appetite’) for something » (Wiktionary) ainsi que pour « feeling a strong desire and determination to succeed » ([The Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/hungry)) :

> *the students are hungry to learn
>
> young and hungry
>
> The coach wants the players to stay hungry. [=to continue feeling a strong desire to win]*

Comment peut-on traduire l'adjectif dans ces phrases, pourquoi peut-on ou non employer « affamé » dans tous les cas ?

Answer (score 4):

En français aussi. "Il a faim" peut signifier qu'il est ambitieux, par exemple. On peut aussi utiliser "avoir soif", peut-être plus fréquemment.

> Les enfants ont soif de savoir.

> jeune et affamé <- non, "ça ne marche pas"

> Le coach veut que les joueurs aient soif de vaincre.

Answer (score 3):

the students are hungry to learn : ... sont **avides de savoir**

young and hungry : jeune et **motivé**

The coach wants the players to stay hungry. [=to continue feeling a strong desire to win] : ... qu'ils restent **combatifs**

"affamé" s'emploie essentiellement au sens propre, toutefois il apparait quelques fois au figuré (source :[Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/affam%C3%A9))

> "Ce cœur nourri de sang et de guerre affamé", Racine, Mithr. II, 3.
> "Si de sang et de mort le ciel est affamé", Racine, Iphig. V, 2.
> "C'était du grand Henri la redoutable armée… lasse du repos et de sang
> affamée", Voltaire, Henr. VI.
> "Ton courage affamé de péril et de gloire, Court d'exploits en exploits, de victoire en victoire",
> Boileau, Sat. VIII. "
> "je ne puis souffrir ces auteurs renommés, Qui,
> dégoûtés de gloire et d'argent affamés", Boileau, A. P. IV.
> "Où sera le juge assez hardi, assez affamé de faire un coupable…", Pellisson, II, 134.
> "Un bel air dont je suis affamée", Sévigné, 445.
> "Je suis affamée de jeûne et de silence", Sévigné, 447.
> "J'y vois des gens > affamés de richesses, des gens affamés d'honneur…", Bourdaloue,
> Pensées, t. I, p. 48.
> "Tous leurs désirs sont satisfaits, et leur plénitude les élève au-dessus de tout ce que les hommes vides etaffamés cherchent sur la terre", Fénelon, Tél. XI.